# How to add a range date slider to a a holoviews plot?

Tags: python, plot, slider, holoviews

I would like to add a date range slider under a holoviews plot, to be able to select the date for which the data is showed in the plot, but I don't manage to do it, could someone please give me a hand?

The code I am using for the plot, without the slider, is as follows:

```
def create_hv_dmap(self, data: DataFrame) -> DynamicMap:
   timeser_plot_opts = hv.opts(title='plot title', fontsize={'title': '16pt'},
                                        xrotation=0, xlabel='Time',
                                        ylabel='measure',
                                        show_legend=True, legend_position='bottom',
                                        gridstyle=GRIDSTYLE, show_grid=True,
                                        yticks=5)


   p_box = GenericStaticPlot.create_generic_static_plot(data, kind='scatter', height=430 + 70, 
       label='', options=timeser_plot_opts)
   p_box_bkh = hv.render(p_box, backend='bokeh')
   p_box_bkh.toolbar.logo = None
   p_box_bkh.toolbar_location = 'above'
   return p_box
```

And the code I am trying to add the slider is the following, copied from another piece of code I found:

```
def create_hv_dmap(self, data: DataFrame) -> DynamicMap:
   import datetime
   enddate = data.index[-1]
   startdate = data.index[0]

   def update(attr, old, new):
      date_selection_low = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(new[0]) / 1000)
      date_selection_high = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(new[1]) / 1000)
      data_selection = grabData(date_selection_low, date_selection_high)
      src.data.update(ColumnDataSource(data_selection).data)

   def grabData(date_selection_low, date_selection_high):
      data_selection = data.loc[date_selection_low:date_selection_high]
      data_selection = 
            data_selection.value_counts().rename_axis('unique_values').reset_index(name='counts')
      return data_selection

   data_selection = grabData(enddate-timedelta(days=1), enddate)
   src = ColumnDataSource(data_selection)


   timeser_plot_opts = hv.opts(title='plot title', fontsize={'title': '16pt'},
                                        xrotation=0, xlabel='Time',
                                        ylabel='measure',
                                        show_legend=True, legend_position='bottom',
                                        gridstyle=GRIDSTYLE, show_grid=True,
                                        yticks=5)


   p_box = GenericStaticPlot.create_generic_static_plot(src, kind='scatter', height=430 + 70, 
       label='', options=timeser_plot_opts)
        
   range_slider = DateRangeSlider(start=startdate, end=enddate, value=(enddate- 
   timedelta(hours=24), enddate), step=1, title="Select range")

   return (column(p_box, range_slider))
```

but I can't see the slider when I run the code, just the plot (as before). Could someone please give me a hand with this?

Thank you in advance,

---

I am trying now a simpler version, just adding the slider (which is doing nothing) to see if it works, and it doesn't. Basically I added this:

```
import panel as pn

# Here, the code for the plot, the first one in this post.

slider = pn.widgets.IntSlider(name='Select date', value=10, start=1, end=365)

return pn.Column(p_box, slider)
```

But I get this error:

HoloViews pane does not support objects of type 'Column'.

---

---

Now I managed to get the plot, but if I try to add the slider (and connect it to the plot), the plot shows nothing and nothing happens if I change the values in the slider.

My dataframe is as follows:

```
| timestamp                 | Values|
| ------------------------- | ----- |
| 2021-09-01 04:00:00+00:00 | 52.46 |
| 2021-09-01 04:10:00+00:00 | 52.76 |
| 2021-09-01 04:10:00+00:00 | 58.42 |
```

And I managed to "make it work" with the following code (I had to change the way I was doing the plot to use Bokeh Figure, apparently it won't work otherwise):

```
def create_hv_dmap(self, data: DataFrame) -> DynamicMap:
    enddate = data.index[-1]
    startdate = data.index[0]

    def update(attr, old, new):
        date_selection_low = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(new[0]) / 1000)  # from 13digit timestamp to date
        date_selection_high = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(new[1]) / 1000)
        data_selection = grabData(date_selection_low, date_selection_high)
        src.data.update(ColumnDataSource(data_selection).data)
        
    def grabData(date_selection_low, date_selection_high):
        data_selection = data.loc[date_selection_low:date_selection_high]
        data_selection = data_selection.value_counts().rename_axis('unique_values').reset_index(name='counts')
        
    data_selection = grabData(enddate-timedelta(days=1), enddate)
    src = ColumnDataSource(pd.DataFrame(data_selection))

    p_bkh = figure(plot_height=430 + 70, title="", toolbar_location=None,
                       tools='hover', plot_width=800, x_axis_type='datetime')

    p_bkh.line(x='timestamp', y='Values', line_width=2, source=src, legend='Values')

    p_bkh.yaxis.axis_label = 'Values'

    slider = DateRangeSlider(start=startdate, end=enddate, value=(startdate, enddate), step=1,
                                       title="Select range")
    slider.on_change('value', update)

    return (column(p_bkh, slider))

def serve(self, plot):
    curdoc().add_root(plot)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your `data` DataFrame? Otherwise it's difficult to undrstand what the problem could be

Comment: Other questions: are you working in a jupyter notebook? If you just run `pn.extension()` and then `pn.widgets.IntSlider(name='Select date', value=10, start=1, end=365)` do you see any widget? If I do the previous steps on my setup I get the slider, so if you don't it's just a problem of visualization of panel objects.

Comment: @gioarma Hi, I just edited the post to add the dataframe I am working with, and the last version of the code I achieved. Now, if I don't plot the slider, the figure is shown correctly, but if I try to add the slider I see both the container of the figure and the slider, but the data is not shown in the plot and changing the slider changes nothing.
Regarding the ```pn.extension()```, I was using it because I copied it from an example I found, but I removed it since it wasn't working either.
Now I think that the problem is the communication between the plot and the slider.